# Отмена последних действий в Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Копирую текст из **Memo2 (Первую строку Memo2**) в Memo1 туда где **установлен** курсор - мышки.

```
Memo1.SetFocus;
Memo1.SetSelTextBuf(PWideChar(Memo2.Lines[0]));
```

**Возник вопрос:** **Как отменить последнее действие ?** То есть после нажатия на кнопку последнее действие должно отмениться.

**Пробовала через (но это отмена только ручных действий и не срабатывает):**

```
Memo1.Undo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто запоминать `Memo1.Lines`.

Вторая строчка,кстати, может выглядеть попроще.

При действии, изменяющем `Memo1.Lines`:

```
TempList.Assign(Memo1.Lines);
Memo1.SelText := Memo2.Lines[0];
```

Восстановление:

```
Memo1.Lines.Assign(TempList);
```

Более продвинутый метод - запоминать только изменения - для этого понадобится какая либо diff-библиотека ([TDiff](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/textdiff.html), [некое обновление](https://github.com/rickard67/TextDiff)), тогда можно не один шаг запоминать.

Comment: Неплохой вариант, спасибо, этот вариант помог.